# Terminal errors concerning netflix in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, streaming

I watched several things in Netflix, and this is the report the terminal gave me about it:

```
$ google-chrome-stable
[6666:6666:1013/203650:ERROR:background_mode_manager_aura.cc(14)] Not implemented reached in virtual void     BackgroundModeManager::EnableLaunchOnStartup(bool)
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[6666:6700:1013/203659:ERROR:channel.cc(307)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
[6666:6700:1013/204700:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -100
[6666:6700:1013/205710:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -100
[6666:6700:1013/210720:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -100
[6666:6700:1013/211731:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -100
[6666:6700:1013/212741:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -100
[6666:6700:1013/213513:ERROR:channel.cc(307)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
[WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
[6666:6700:1013/213751:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -100
Vector smash protection is enabled.
[WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
[6666:6700:1013/214802:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -100
Vector smash protection is enabled.
[6666:6700:1013/215812:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -100
[6666:6700:1013/220822:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -100
[6666:6700:1013/221832:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -100
[6666:6700:1013/222843:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -100
[6666:6700:1013/223853:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -100
[6666:6700:1013/224332:ERROR:channel.cc(307)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
```

I did not have any problems (at least as far as I could tell), but these reports kind of concern me.
What does it mean?

Comment: The part about the connection being broken I kind of get, because I closed the lid of my laptop, thus closing the internet connection. But all the other things I don't understand

Comment: OK, try it without closing the lid

Comment: Well did it work with the lid open?

Comment: Sorry, i thought you were kind of joking there.... I get the same error reports now and haven't closed the lid yet.

Comment: OK.  It was worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the required Widevine and Pepper Flash (PPAPI) modules are installed in your version of Chrome.
Google Chrome -> Address bar: chrome://plugins

Both the required modules should be visible:
Widevine Content Decryption Module
Adobe Flash Player Version
This should be a PPAPI Version 11.7 or greater.

Also if you are a nexflix user alot I would look into the nexflix app for ubuntu. 
Sudo apt-get netflix-desktop

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop

Comment: I have Adobe Flash Player - Version: 19.0.0.185
Shockwave Flash 19.0 r0 and 
Widevine Content Decryption Module - Version: 1.4.8.824
Enables Widevine licenses for playback of HTML audio/video content. (version: 1.4.8.824). The command to get the netflix app didn't work. It said " invalid operation netflix-desktop"

Comment: I also tried sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop. Then it said " unable to locate package netflix-desktop"

Comment: sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop

Comment: Ok, that worked, but it told me this : MS true type fonts are not properly installed, would you like to download and install them now? (requires an Internet connection and sudo permissions). I installed it by using the command line : sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer. Then it gave me some disclamer thing in the terminal, and I have to hit <ok> but I have no idea how to hit <ok> Enter doesn't work, scrolling doesn't work.. Argh

Comment: Accept and sudo apt-get clean

Comment: Nexflix desktop will be available once finished downloading.

Comment: I don't know how to accept. That's the problem. It won't let me hit " ok" so I'm stuck at the disclaimer of ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Comment: Ok is usually enter or "y"

Comment: Ok, i was being stupid. I just needed to hit the 'tab' button to be able to navigate. So i installed it all, and it seems to work, only it refuses to start a movie. It just keeps on buffering. This is what it says in the terminal: netflix-desktop
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 1.7.52 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}

Comment: Might need to update pakages older code sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: I did all that, but it still keeps buffering :( Anyway, maybe I should open a new topic? Because I get warnings that the discussion is getting too long :p